# Using Background Worker and process.start not able to retrieve progress status

Tags: backgroundworker, process.start

Good evening,

I just started playing around with C# and I tried creating a GUI for a program that runs in command line. I have been able to get it running, but now I am stuck trying to implement a progress bar to it.

I have read other post but I am unable to find the exact issue or to understand how to apply the solution to my issue.

Here is my code (apologize if this is very messy):

```
private void MethodToProcess(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
    {
        // Set all the strings for passthrough
        String USMTPath_Work = USMTPath + USMTArch;
        String USMTPath_full = USMTPath_Work + @"\Scanstate.exe";
        String USMTFlags_Capture = @"/c /v:13 /o /l:scanstate.log /localonly /efs:copyraw";
        String Argument_full = SavePath + XML1 + XML2 + USMTFlags_Capture;

        // Test that USMT path is correct            
        if (USMTPath == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: There is no USMT Path defined.");
            return;
        }

        // Test that Windows folder is correct when offline
        /* if (Windows_Path == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: There is no Windows Path to capture.");
            return;
        } */

        // Runs the capture
        System.Diagnostics.Process Scanstate = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        Scanstate.StartInfo.FileName = USMTPath_full;
        Scanstate.StartInfo.Arguments = Argument_full;
        Scanstate.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Scanstate.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = USMTPath_Work;
        //Scanstate.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        Scanstate.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        //Scanstate.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        Scanstate.Start();
        Scanstate.WaitForExit();

        String Str_ExitCode = Scanstate.ExitCode.ToString();

        if (Scanstate.ExitCode == 1)
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Data has not been captured. Please check the log files for details.");
        if (Scanstate.ExitCode == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Success: Data has been captured. For more information, check log files.");
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Unknown error has occurred. Please check the log files for details.");
            MessageBox.Show("Error Code: " + Str_ExitCode);
        }

        Scanstate.Close();

    }
```

Basically, I am trying to run the process scanstate.exe. Now, I am trying to run backgroundworker in order to be able to retrieve progress and pass it to the progressbar.

```
 private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        progressBar1.Step = 1;

        BackgroundWorker CaptureBG = new BackgroundWorker();
        CaptureBG.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        CaptureBG.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(MethodToProcess);
        CaptureBG.RunWorkerCompleted +=new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(CaptureBG_RunWorkerCompleted);
        CaptureBG.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(CaptureBG_ProgressChanged);
        CaptureBG.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

and

```
        private void CaptureBG_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 100;
    }

    private void CaptureBG_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        progressBar1.Value++;
    }
```

However I am either missunderstanding the use or I am missing something, since the process runs, but I don't get any progress on the progressbar. It only fills once the process finish.

What am I doing wrong? In general, how would a process report progress if I don't know exactly how long is going to take?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *BackgroundWorker* is responsible for updating the progress as it gets further complete with its task.

There is no interaction between your process that you launch and your code that would provide progress *of that process* back to your code.

In order for this to work, two things have to happen:

1. You need to define a mechanism for your *process* to report progress to the *BackgroundWorker*.
2. The *BackgroundWorker* must update its own progress by calling the [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress%28v=vs.90%29) method so that the *ProgressChanged* event is fired.

The first step is the tricky one and depends on how *scanstate.exe* works.  Does it do anything to give an indication of progress, such as write to the console?  If so, you can redirect the console output and parse that output to determine or at least estimate progress.

**UPDATE**

[Scanstate.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560781%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) provides the ability to write progress to a log, e.g.:

```
scanstate /i:migapp.xml /i:miguser.xml \\fileserver\migration\mystore /progress:prog.log /l:scanlog.log
```

You could use a [FileWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) in your BackgroundWorker to look for changes to the progress log and update progress accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are saying and it makes sense. Now I am looking at FileWatcher, and based on MSDN, it shows that can detect a change in a folder or a file. With that I would get my ProgressChanged to trigger, is that correct? Also, is there a way to have FileWatcher or similar look for a specific string (for example, trigger a progresschanged when it finds the string "Stage 2 of 4" ,"Stage 3 of 4" or "Stage 4 of 4"?  Thanks.

Comment: You would use FileWatcher to know *when* the file changes.  You would then have to read the contents of the file and examine those to know what your progress looks like.  You can use File.ReadAllText to conveniently read the file contents into a string variable. I don't have stanstate on my computer so I can't see what the output looks like.

Comment: Now I understand. I will go ahead and try implementing the solution. I hope it works. Thanks for the explanation and the info.